# Using jQuery to get data attribute values with .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, custom-data-attribute

I have the following HTML with data attributes - I want to write some jQuery that will loop through the HTML and collect the data attributes and put them into an array - could anyone assist as I'm getting an error.

I am trying to use the data() attribute - can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<span class="winners" data-userid="123" data-position="1" data-fullname="neil">
<span class="winners" data-userid="234" data-position="2" data-fullname="Ron">
<span class="winners" data-userid="421" data-position="3" data-fullname="Philip">
```

```js
var multi = $('.winners');
var winners_array = [];

$.each(multi, function (index, item) {
    winners_array.push( {name: 'fullname', value: item.data('fullname')} );  
});

console.log(winners_array);
```

Console error:

> `item.data` is not a function

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`item` is not a jQuery object, the arguments for `each` are the index and the native DOM element

```
var multi = $('.winners');
var winners_array = [];

$.each(multi, function (index, item) {
    winners_array.push( {name: 'fullname', value: $(item).data('fullname')} );  
});
```

using a map would be easier

```
var winners_array = $.map($('.winners'), function(el) {
     return {name: 'fullname', value: $(el).data('fullname')}
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I understand you should use $(item), instead data only. Kindly find the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var multi = $('.winners');
        var winners_array = [];

        $.each(multi, function (index, item) {
            winners_array.push( {name: 'fullname', value: $(item).data('fullname')} );  
        });

        console.log(winners_array);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use item.dataset.fullname instead.

```
var multi = $('.winners');
var winners_array = [];

$.each(multi, function (index, item) {
    winners_array.push( {name: 'fullname', value: item.dataset.fullname} );  
});

console.log(winners_array);
```

Comment: This is only supported in IE11, and generally isn't supported in older browsers at all. You'd be better of using `getAttribute('data-fullname')`. Also note that jQuery's `data()` stores data internally, so if the value is set or changed with `data()` this won't work either.

Comment: Are you sure? I just verified it in the Chrome console.