# How to get data attribute values from multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How will I be able to get all the values of `data-val` by only using `class` not `id`? I can only get the first one. I think this can be accomplished by using loop, but I'm not really sure.

```js
/* JS */

var dataValue = $('.test').data('val');
$('#result').append('Result: ' + dataValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div data-val="1" class="test"></div>
<div data-val="2" class="test"></div>
<div data-val="3" class="test"></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Not a duplicate of [Using jQuery to get data attribute values with .each()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307137/using-jquery-to-get-data-attribute-values-with-each) because I'm not asking `HOW` to use `.each()` I'm asking WHAT to use and there is no `each()` function in the original post.

Comment: maybe you should get data from each element $( ".test" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( data  + ": " + $( this ).data("val") );
});

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to get data attribute values with .each()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307137/using-jquery-to-get-data-attribute-values-with-each)

Comment: @Velthune I think this is not a duplicate because In my original post there is no .each() function and I'm not sure what function will I use. If I know `.each()` before then I shouldn't asked this question in the first place.

Comment: your question is already answer in many post. You simply should search before asking.

Comment: @Velthune I know how to search. But it's not easy to search if you don't know the exact string. Don't want to argue with toxic people just do what you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list to get:

Instead of modifying the DOM on each iteration, append it a string/array and then add it to the dom:

```js
var array = [];
$(".test").each(function() {
    array.push($(this).data("val"));
});
$("#result").append("Results "+array.join(","))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div data-val="1" class="test"></div>
<div data-val="2" class="test"></div>
<div data-val="3" class="test"></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure what will I accept. Almost the same with @Akskay.

Comment: I modified it for performance reason. @Akskay is appending it in each iteration. I was first to answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```js
/* JS */

 $('.test').each(function(){
 var dataValue = $(this).data('val');
   $('#result').append(dataValue);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div data-val="1" class="test"></div>
<div data-val="2" class="test"></div>
<div data-val="3" class="test"></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what do you want as a result. Counted values or values separated by `something`? This case gets every value into the array.

```
var result = [];
$(".test").each(function() {
    result.push($(this).data("val"));
});

$('#result').append('Result: ' + result.join(', '));
```